# Browser Extension "browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener" works on Chrome but not on Firefox if tab auto reloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I sucessfully inject a content script to a site for the first time. If I filled out some input fields the site hard reloads (to show some additional informations) and kills also my content script.

In my Chrome Extension I have a workaround for this:

```
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  const tabURL = 'my-site.com';
  if (tab.url.includes(tabURL) && changeInfo.title && changeInfo.title.includes(tabURL)) {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: `
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
          new MyApp();
        });`
    });
  }
});
```

The problem is, it does not work in Firefox as a Firefox extension.
I use the Firefox [webextension-polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill)

Is there another "workaround" which works for Firefox?
OR
How can I detect if a page / tab reloads in firefox (e.g. from background script)? (And also reload my content script again)

Comment: The listener works but your condition doesn't: the `title` won't be present on reload.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the answer, because it works :)

```
// CHROME Version
  if (tab.url.includes(tabURL) && changeInfo.title && changeInfo.title.includes(tabURL)
  // FIREFOX VERSION
  || tab.url.includes(tabURL) && changeInfo.status === 'complete')
```